# Discrete Sets in Certain Metric Spaces are Countable

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I've recently started my first real analysis course, and we're studying metric spaces from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Baby Rudin).

We have the following definition:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $A \subset X$. A point $p \in A$ is said to be isolated if $p$ is not a limit point of $A$. Furthermore, $A$ is said to be discrete if all its points are isolated.

Now, consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Prove that if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is discrete, then it is at most countable.

What I had in mind was something along the lines of:

Since we know that for every $p \in A$ there exist some $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $B_{r}(p)  \cap A = \left \{ p \right \}$. We can find some rational $q$ with $0<q<r$, and isolate $p$ with the ball of radius $q$. Then we define a function which assings to each $p$ said $q$. If said function were injective, we would be done, but I don't know how to do that, since all points in $A$ could very well be isolated by finitely many different reals $r$.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

PS: I've previously shown that a discrete set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact if and only if it is finite. But it could not think of any useful ways to apply this to the problem at hand.

Comment: The title is blatantly wrong. Let $d$ be the discrete metric on $\Bbb R$, namely $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\neq y$ (and $0$ otherwise, of course). Then $\Bbb R$ itself is an uncountable discrete set in a metric space. It is true, however, that in $\Bbb R^n$ discrete sets are countable.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Show that for each point $p\in A$ there is an open ball $B$ with rational **center** and radius, such that $B\cap A=\{p\}$. (I.e., the radius is a rational number, the center is a point in $\mathbb R^n$ all of whose coordinates are rational numbers.) The set of all such balls is countable.

Answer (score -1):

In reference to the hint,we do the following. 
Choose  r positive real such that B:= B(p,r)'s closure, has no point of A other than p.let (r(n)) be a sequence of rational coordinates in B(p,r)such that it converges to p.Let s(n)=d(r(n),bdB) and let p(n)=d(r(n),p) for all n. p(n) converges to 0 and s(n) converges to r.
Let  v(n)=s(n)-2p(n) for all n.Thus v(n) converges to r.Since r is positive,there exists N a natural number,
Such that v(N)=s(N)-2p(N)is positive.Hence 2p(N) is strictly less than s(N).
B(r(N),2p(N)) is contained in B(p,r) since Eucledian balls are convex and straight lines in Eucledian spaces are connected.
Now there exists a positive rational t such that t is in between p(N) and 2p(N). Also r(N) is rational in all coordinates.Hence B(r(N),t) is inside B thus B(r(N),t) has p as the only point of A. 
(Note p is in B(r(N),t)). Hence is the proof.